# what type of joint I need if I want to rotate on both x and y axis?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

since "revolute" can only rotate on one axis..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406848/what-type-of-joint-i-need-if-i-want-to-rotate-on-both-x-and-y-axis?/) by [Yibin](https://answers.ros.org/users/118655/yibin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, that feature is not supported by either ros or gazebo. The closest solution you can get that works in ros is to use two revolute joints connected by a short link.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yibin](https://answers.ros.org/users/118655/yibin/) on 2022-09-23**:
got it Thanks a lot sir!!

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2022-09-26**:
even though this is a `ROS` question, for reference, gazebo *does* support [universal joints (e.g. x-y free, z constrained)](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/4.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1UniversalJoint.html) and [ball joints (xyz free)](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/4.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1BallJoint.html), but this is SDF only. for URDF models, you can add concentric revolute/continuous joints as mentioned.